# How can I programmatically add multiple list fragments to a single activity?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

Apologies as I am an Android novice.  I'm trying to programmatically add multiple list fragments to a single activity, but when I do, only one is displayed.  How can I display multiple lists in a single action?

The end goal is to read a set of data from an API and categorize it into multiple lists in my application.  I would like the data to be horizontally scrolling list fragments, but since that's an additional complication I've started with simple ListFragments.  My code looks like this:

activity_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  />
```

ItemActivity:

```
public class ItemActivity extends FragmentActivity
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        ItemListFragment fragment1 = new ItemListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment1);        
        ItemListFragment fragment2 = new ItemListFragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment2);
        transaction.commit();

    }
}
```

ItemListFragment:

```
public class ItemListFragment extends ListFragment {    
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        items.add("One");
        items.add("Two");
        items.add("Three");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: "would like the data to be horizontally scrolling list fragments"
So, you want the list to be vertically and horizontally scrolled?

Comment: At the end I want a set of n lists that can horizontally scroll.  The lists don't have to be in a list but could just be separate fragments.  I'm not worrying about the horizontal lists yet, just providing it as a reason why I want multiple lists in the activity.

Comment: Zyoo's answer is technically correct, but I went another route.  I just created a Scroll View with multiple Horizontal scroll views to achieve what I wanted.  It's not really two ListFragments on a page, but it's what I actually wanted.

Comment: you should know that scrollview doesn't recycle the views, so careful with outofmemoryerror if your list item is sufficiently large

Comment: I ended up using a fantastic library for a HorizontalListView to solve this exact problem: https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple lists in one `Activity`, here's what I usually do:

1. Because every `ListView` is using independent scrolling view, I usually split the screen for every ListView I have. Example: with 2 `ListView` i split the height of the screen 50/50 so every `ListView` have 50% portion of the screen.
2. If I have to dynamically add `ListView` to the screen, I use [cwac merge adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) to merge the adapter and display it in a single `ListView`
3. Another alternative you can just use `ViewPager` to display `ListFragment`. This would achieve what you want, which is having multiple listviews in a single activity.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldnt you do it this way?

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();
// work here to change Activity fragments (add, remove, etc.).  Example here of adding.
fragmentTransaction.add (R.id.myFrame, myFrag);
fragmentTransaction.commit ()
```

i found this code, so as just one is displayed, commit each transaction in your code.

```
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    ItemListFragment fragment1 = new ItemListFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment1).commit();
    transaction = manager.beginTransaction(); // might be unnescessary
    ItemListFragment fragment2 = new ItemListFragment();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment2).commit();
```

if this throws some sort of error, you might need to start another transaction for adding the second fragment.

Comment: The fragments are not views, so I think I can't do this. Maybe I should be restructuring the Activity in some other way so it doesn't use fragments?

Comment: oh sorry my fault. but you can add them in an xml, so there has to be a way to add them programmatically

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing.  Both fragments get added but only one shows up.

Comment: no your code is different from mine. You are calling commit just once. and i asusme thats why just one fragment appears.